# What does the standalone “-” do in these tar and gzip commands?

Tags: linux, bash

Please help to figure this out . I couldn't find it in man file , what exactly "-" does here?

Thank you, sorry for being silly.

```
tar cf - B | gzip - > B.tar.gz
```

Comment: I too couldn't find it in `man tar`, the man page could be improved. But `man gzip` states: `If no files are specified, or if a file name is "-", the standard input is compressed to
       the standard output.`